# Shameless use of the site for homework problems

Tags: discussion, behavior, ethics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

What's the policy for brazen use of the site for homework, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257643/time-complexity-of-function-in-scheme)?

Comment: related : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions